How to create a dynamically imported strategy pattern in pydantic?
I would like to implement a strategy pattern in pydantic, by taking the strategy string, importing it as a module, retrieving the model for that item for it, and continue model validation with the dynamically imported model.
For example:
data = {
  "shape": {
    "strategy": "mypkg.Cone",
    "radius": 5,
    "height": 10
  }
  "transformations": [
    {
      "strategy": "mypkg.Translate",
      "x": 10,
      "y": 10,
      "z": 10
    },
    {
      "strategy": "quaternions.Rotate",
      "quaternion": [0, 0, 0, 0]
    }
  ]
}

I'd like this to be contained within the model class, and arbitrarily recursive so that I can just use Model(**data) and all strategies are resolved, and so that strategy-loaded models can have their own substrategies.
From this input I'd expect the following validated instance:
<__main__.Model(
  shape=<mypkg.Cone(
    radius=5,
    height=10
  )>,
  transformations=[
    <mypkg.Translate(x=10, y=10, z=10)>,
    <quaternions.Rotate(quaternion=[0,0,0,0])>
  ]
)>

The closest I have gotten is to use try to force rebuild the model during validation and to dynamically add new members to the discriminated type unions, but it only takes effect the NEXT validation cycle of the model:
class Model:
  shape: Shape
  transformations: list[Transformation]

  @model_validator(mode="before")
  def adjust_unions(cls, data):
    cls.model_fields.update({"shape": import_and_add_to_union(cls, data, "shape")})
    cls.model_rebuild(force=True)
    return data

import_and_add_to_union takes the existing FieldInfo, imports the module, retrieves the
new union member, and produces a new FieldInfo with an annotation for a discriminated type union, with both the existing union members, and the newly imported one. This works correctly, but only goes into effect the NEXT validation cycle:
try:
  Model(**data) # errors
except:
  pass
try:
  # Now works, but would error out once more for every nested
  # level of substrategies any of the strategies may have.
  Model(**data)
except:
  pass

on top of that I would like the Shape model to be a self contained strategy pattern, that when validated with strategy: cone returns an instance a validated instance of Cone instead. Now the Shape class requires its parent model to be aware that it is a strategy model and the parent needs to build the discriminated type union.
Is there any way to improve this?

It seems like the optimal solution can be achieved in a much simpler way by overriding __init__ and calling the appropriate class's __pydantic_validator__ manually, and then overriding the instance's class:
class Strategy(BaseModel):
    strategy: str

    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # Code to import the module and load the class
        qualifiers = kwargs.get("strategy").split(".")
        module = ".".join(qualifiers[:-1])
        attr = qualifiers[-1]
        module_ref = importlib.import_module(module)
        child_cls = getattr(module_ref, attr)

        # Override __class__
        object.__setattr__(self, "__class__", child_cls)
        # Code for pydantic validation to continue with the new class
        child_cls.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(
            kwargs,
            self_instance=self,
        )

any class that inherits from Strategy will then be loaded according to the value of its strategy attribute. In an example module called my.pkg:
class Cone(Strategy):
    radius: float
    height: float

and then from anywhere:
>>> Strategy(strategy="my.pkg.Cone", radius=3, height=5)
Cone(strategy='my.pkg.Cone', radius=3.0, height=5.0)

This approach can even be considering "supported" because it appears in the docs as the recommended way to deal with context in the BaseModel initializer.

While at first this looks like an elegant solution, I would suggest to not bind the string to the actual class name and location in the package. This will make maintenance more difficult in future. For example when classes are renamed or moved, old files will not resolve and lead to an error.
Instead I would recommend to define an independent tag instead. This allows you to work with a Pydantic standard pattern: a discriminated union.
Here is a minimal example:
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Annotated, Literal, Union

class Strategy(BaseModel):
    pass


# The subclasses can live in the same file or
# in different files, as long as they inherit from Strategy
class Cone(Strategy):
    strategy: Literal["my-cone"] = "my-cone"
    radius: float
    height: float


class Translate(Strategy):
    strategy: Literal["my-translate"] = "my-translate"
    x: float
    y: float
    z: float


class Rotate(Strategy):
    strategy: Literal["my-rotate"] = "my-rotate"
    quaternion: tuple[float, float, float, float]


def get_all_subclasses(cls):
    """Get subclasses"""
    for subclass in cls.__subclasses__():
        yield from get_all_subclasses(subclass)
        yield subclass


sub_classes = tuple(get_all_subclasses(Strategy))
AnyStrategy = Annotated[Union[sub_classes], Field(discriminator="strategy")]


class Model(BaseModel):
    shape: AnyStrategy
    transformations: list[AnyStrategy]

data = {
  "shape": {
    "strategy": "my-cone",
    "radius": 5,
    "height": 10
  },
  "transformations": [
    {
      "strategy": "my-translate",
      "x": 10,
      "y": 10,
      "z": 10
    },
    {
      "strategy": "my-rotate",
      "quaternion": [0, 0, 0, 0]
    }
  ]
}

Model(**data)

Which returns:
Model(shape=Cone(strategy='my-cone', radius=5.0, height=10.0), transformations=[Translate(strategy='my-translate', x=10.0, y=10.0, z=10.0), Rotate(strategy='my-rotate', quaternion=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))])

While this introduced the minimal burden to keep a strategy tag on your sub-classes, I think it leads to longterm more stable and easier to maintain code.
If you really care about the solution with the package locations and class names, you might be able to automatically generate those using callable discriminators.
I hope this helps!

Yes, the requirements I outlined in my question are hard requirements. The discriminated union is unknown before the start of validation, so I can in no way define Union[sub_classes] or get_all_subclasses, because they haven't been imported yet, and are dynamic unknowns, which is why I need the module and attr name. This is simply the nature of the problem. I was aware of discriminated unions, and even implemented a solution that automatically constructs them based on the content. I will also post that solution. Nevertheless, thank you for your well constructed answer!

I see. However it is important to understand that this "undermines" the intended usage of a statically defined model in Pydantic. The model represents a fixed schema after it has been defined. Your case is probably rather covered a dynamically defined model using e.g. create_model(), where the types can be defined at runtime.
